# Помощь с решением

Tags: python

```py
gi = int(input()) 
i=0 
qwer = 0 
while i<7: 
    xf = map(int,input().split())
    if gi in xf: 
        qwer += 1 
    i+=1
print ("0")
print (qwer)
```

Разделил элементы как посчитать дублирующие элементы втором столбце
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы же не написали вообще нормально суть задания, дублирующие элементы второй строке - это что такое?

Comment: Им нужно чтобы только 2 столбец проверялся

Comment: in xf[1::2] попробуйте вместо просто in xf.

Comment: Все решил спасибо и еще надо было добавить list
xf = list(map(int,input().split()))
    if gi in xf[1::2]: